# How to add widget to layout in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

Is there a way to add widget to the layout xml? I know about the layout updates from the backend, but I wanted to know if there is a way to add widgets the same way as static blocks?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can add widget via followings xml ,

```
<referenceContainer name="content.top">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\Widget\Link" name="demoBlock" template="widget/static_block/default.phtml">
        <action method="setData">
            <argument name="id_path" xsi:type="string">category/20</argument>
            <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">Demo Category Title</argument>
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">category/widget/link/link_inline.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

you need to update followings

- referenceContainer as per you needs
- Block Class & Template (if you require to update the template for block)
- arguments in setData

Comment: Is there a way to specify a widget that has already been created in the backend? Maybe by using the widget id?

Comment: there is no need to do that in layout files 
admin widgets directly loads to selected configuration , there is configuration on each widget where you want to display that.

Comment: It works and I can set custom template as well. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this with a custom widget that needed some arguments. They weren’t send to the widget correctly. After changing <action method="setData"> to <arguments> It worked like a charm.